# Implementation of Normalized Cut (Spectral Clustering) for Image Segmentation

Tags: image-processing, matlab, computer-vision, image-segmentation, graph-theory

I have implemented "normalized cut" segmentation. The change here is that, instead of giving an image as input, I have given an matrix of image. As my output looks odd to me. I need to know whether my implementation is correct or not. 
Code:

```
clear all
tic;
% im = imread('lena.pgm');
im =[94 122 99 101 111 101;
99 92 103 87 107 116;
93 109 113 84 86 106;
5 17 6 54 56 53;
13 11 5 56 44 50;
0 10 5 49 42 51];
% resizing to avoid out of memory error
% cim=imresize(im,[100 100]);
cim=im;
[r, c]=size(cim);  
ind=find(cim);
lind=length(ind);
[I,J]=ind2sub([r,c],ind);

% % I've used linear indexing to speed up the partitioning
% vectoring the pixel nodes
for i=1:lind
       V1(i)=double(cim(ind(i)));
end

% normalizing to [0-1] scale
V=(V1./255);   

% w is the weight matrix (similarity matrix or adjacency matrix)
w=zeros(lind,lind);

% r, sigmaI, sigmaX values
rad=4.5;
sigi=10;
sigx=25;

% computing the weight matrix
for i=1:lind
    x1=I(i,1);
    y1=J(i,1);

    for j=1:lind
         if (i==j)
                 w(i,j)=1;
         else          
                 x2=I(j,1);
                 y2=J(j,1);

            dist=((x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2);  
            if sqrt(dist)>=rad
                dx=0;            
            else
                dx=exp(-((dist)/(sigx^2)));
            end

            pdiff=(V(i)-V(j))^2;
            di=exp(-((pdiff)/(sigi)^2));  
            w(i,j)=di*dx;
        end

    end
end

d=zeros(lind,lind);
s=sum(w,2);

% the diagonal matrix for computing the laplacian matrix
for i=1:lind
     d(i,i)=s(i);
end

A=zeros(lind,lind);
A=(d-w); % A is the laplacian matrix

%  vt has the eigen vectors corresponding to eigen values in vl
%  other eigs / eig functions in matlab can be used but I'm using the
%  function to compute the 5 smallest eigenvectors
[vt,vl]=eigs(A,d,5,'sm');

% se has the second smallest eigen vector, third and so on
se=vt(:,2:4);

% % % % % Simultaneous 'k' partitions
k=6;
id=kmeans(se,k);
imp=cell(1,k);
pic=cell(1,k);

for i=1:k
    imp{1,i}= find(id(:,1)==i);
    mat=zeros(100,100);
    in=imp{1,i};
    mat(in)=cim(in);
    pic{1,i}=uint8(mat);
%     figure,imshow(pic{1,i});
end

% pic has the sub graphs or partitiond sub images
figure;
subplot(2,4,1);imshow(uint8(im));title('Original image');
subplot(2,4,2);imshow(uint8(cim));title('Preprocessed image');
subplot(2,4,3);imshow(pic{1,1});title('Partition 1');
subplot(2,4,4);imshow(pic{1,2});title('Partition 2');
subplot(2,4,5);imshow(pic{1,3});title('Partition 3');
subplot(2,4,6);imshow(pic{1,4});title('Partition 4');
subplot(2,4,7);imshow(pic{1,5});title('Partition 5');
subplot(2,4,8);imshow(pic{1,6});title('Partition 6');
toc;
```

Output:
[image]
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. The distance function should be applied on the values of the pixels. You may add the spatial distance but in order to have proper segmentation over edges you need the value information in the distance function.
2. Check for multiplicity of the 0 eigen value. It might happen. If it does, you should skip all eigen vectors related to that eigen values of 0.
3. Usually euclidean distance is not optimized for pixels. Think of other distances.
4. Most of the operations you do in loop can be vectorized. For exampli squared eucludean distance and the extraction of the diagonal values.